# Safari - LocalStorage from same site sub.domain.com to domain.com not working

Tags: safari, local-storage, postmessage

Case is a subdomain like "es.site.com" is used for spanish region, and "us.site.com" for us region, "m.site.com" for a mobile dedicated content, or a global version "site.com" is possible.

Users should be able to be logged across all same site subdomains:
When user logins in "es.site.com" if visiting "site.com" must be logged.

This was done using an iframe in "es.site.com" that postMessages to the main parent domain "site.com". This site.com then can call API login etc and store some user data in localStorage or sometimes sessionStorage or even a cookie for that domain.

With the new Safari Anti Tracking (Safari's Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) partitions browser storage) this is totally broken! How can this be solved? These sites are not Third parties since they are same site "site.com"  nor advertisers.